# Trying to combine multiple imported excel files in R into one long file

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I am using RStudio to practice data cleaning and visualization in R.  I downloaded and imported several excel files into R Studio.  But now, I want to combine the 5 separate files into one long file so I can conduct analysis on the different places.  Each excel file is a different location regarding home sales.  I want to combine all of the files into one so I can develop insights into which location does better as far as sales during different times of the year, which location has the best month out of each year, etc.  Is there a way to combine the separate imported files into one massive file?

I haven't tried it yet, but I was wondering if I need to possibly combine the files while in excel into one large file.  Then import the one file into R.  Am I on the right track?  Can I combine the files once they're individually imported into R?

Comment: You can readily do this in R, but also it's possible in Excel.  Which is "best" is hard to specify.  If you just need to do it once and won't need to refer to the original files again for any reason then go ahead and combine in Excel.  If the files might get individually updated or other people use them, then a re-usable R script might be more appropriate.  Both are legitimate options.  Given what you're trying to do (practice data cleaning and visualisation in R) I'd do it in R just for the learning experience.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen - Thanks for that.  I will look at 2 of the files and see if they have the same number of columns as the other 3.  I know 3 of the 5 have the same number of columns which would make the bind_rows function the way to go.  But if they don't I may make separate files for all 5 with the same columns and try merging the 5 then.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "How to combine dataframes" is a frequent question on SO, and a quick search (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+combine+dataframes ) will bring up answers for various use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do they have the same column names?

Then you can import them into R individually and merge them using the function bind_rows()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).